# cordova-plugin-fcm Icon customisation

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have some doubt about the icon placing, I searched in google and I apply many solutions but none of them worked.

I generated icons using http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=fcm_push_icon
used their default for testing but still not working

In README it only says place `fcm_push_icon.png` in res dir so I place `[cordova_project_dir]/res` and place the `drawable-XXXX` in the same dir. I don't know what I did wrong.

Cordova 8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

copy icon in `[cordova_project_dir]/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/`

`drawable-hdpi
drawable-land-hdpi
drawable-land-ldpi
drawable-land-mdpi
drawable-land-xhdpi
drawable-land-xxhdpi
drawable-land-xxxhdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-port-hdpi
drawable-port-ldpi
drawable-port-mdpi
drawable-port-xhdpi
drawable-port-xxhdpi
drawable-port-xxxhdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xxxhdpi`

with different sizes according to folder in the name `fcm_push_icon.png`

generate a png transparent file (I did it in 1024*1024px) for your white icon which will be displayed in the status bar
upload it in the [Android Notification Icon Generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=fcm_push_icon)

Comment: Create a specific folder or the folder added the image